# What Is Your First Impression / Perception Of These Family Names For An Anti-Hero Protagonist?

Tags: kanji, names

Writing a book and I want to know how the average Japanese person perceives these names, they are all supposedly family names. The character is a good guy in the story but does some bad things, like beating up someone who he can't prove is guilty to the police.

Takumi 匠実
Takami 貴水
Kaneki 金生 / 金木
Kirishima 霧嶋

Comment: [We don't handle subjective/open-ended questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) like this one. To me, 匠実 and 貴水 look more like a given name, and 金生 seems simply unfamiliar and odd.

Comment: What Kanji should be used for a Family Name "Takumi"?

Comment: Are the rest okay?

Comment: Takumi is usually a given name. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shu_Takumi) is the only person I know whose family name is Takumi (巧). 金木 and 霧嶋 are okay.

Comment: [匠](https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=匠) and [内匠](https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=内匠) exist as last names, but they are very rare. There is also [宅見](https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=宅見). [高見](https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=高見) is common for Takami. [鷹見](https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=鷹見) is much rarer.

Comment: Nobunaga or Rance should fit with this kind of character :D